# How to get started after building the source code?

Tags: scala-native

I managed to build and run the demos of scala-native however I can't find any getting started guide to setup the runtime, is it just too early?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a proof of concept with pre-requisites, installation instructions and the first baby steps I've discovered along the way. It's a project I use as template for other projects based on Scala Native. I hope it helps: http://github.com/frgomes/poc-scala-native.

Answer (score 0):

We've not officially released a stable version of the project yet. Please stay tuned for the first developer preview that is going to happen in near future. It's going to be announced via [our twitter account](https://twitter.com/scala_native).